# Best way to test global npm modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

Lets say I develop a global npm module called **mytool** that registers a env variable through "bin" in package.json with the name **mytool**.

So after I install it globally by typing

```
npm install mytool -g
```

then I can type `mytool --someOption` in terminal and handle the CLI input in javascript. Now lets assume that mytool works a lot with the current working directory of the CLI, so to just

```
node index.js --someOption
```

is a bad idea.

However to test for bugs I don't want to push a new version of "mytool" to npm and then install it globally from npm. Rather I want to be able to test this all locally.

Question: What is the best way to do test global npm modules without publishing to npm?

Comment: If the answer solves your question, please check it as accepted ;)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted or, if the answer doesn't solve your question completely, just inform it :)

Answer (score 4):

#### [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)

Contrary to what it seems, `npm link` can also be used in your case, too.

**Just run it on the root folder of your project.** No additional arguments are necessary.

Using it in you package folder will create a symlink in the global folder **`{prefix}/lib/node_modules/<package>`** that links to the package where the npm link command was executed.

It will also link any bins in the package to **`{prefix}/bin/{name}`**.